# Calling Custom request validation from resource controller

Tags: php, laravel-5

I need help to validate using Custom request class validation but since my controller is a resource controller I can't add the custom request class as parameter. Any ideas how to call custom request validation from resource controller?

This is the route to my Resource Controller

```
Route::resource('customers', 'CustomerController');
```

And this is my Customer Request class

```
class CustomerRequest extends Request
{
    //...
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'customer_type'=>'required|',
            'customer_vendor'=>'required|',
            'customer_name'=>'required|',
            'company_name'=>'required_if:customer_type,Company',
            'job_position'=>'required|',
            'street'=>'',
            'city'=>'required|',
            'country'=>'required|',
            'website'=>'url',
            'phone'=>'required_unless:mobile|',
            'mobile'=>'required_unless:phone|',
            'email'=>'email',
        ];
    }
}
```

And this is my Resource controller:

```
class CustomerController extends Controller
{
    // ....
    // Add Customer
    public function store()
    {
        //how do i call custom request validation here

        return view('create_views/new_customer',['title' => 'New Customer','nav_links'=>CustomerController::$Links]);
    }    
}
```

**SOLVED**

When you create the custom request using php artisan the authorise function is returning false and we need to return true if we are logged in:

```
public function authorize()
{
    return false;//should be return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

When you create the custom request using php artisan the authorise function is returning false and we need to return true if we are logged in:

```
public function authorize()
{
    return false;//should be return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to type-hint the request (`CustomerRequest`) on your controller method (`store()`).

```
public function store(CustomerRequest $request)
{
    return view('create_views/new_customer',['title' => 'New Customer','nav_links'=>CustomerController::$Links]);
}
```

Comment: I tried it earlier, It returns a forbidden page! but I can type-hint `public function store(Request $request)`

Comment: are you logged in as an user?

Comment: Yes, I'm logged in, I also tried disabling `$this->middleware('auth');` and authrize(). The issue is this is a resource controller, in a regular controller the type-hint works perfectly.